# How to convert torchscript model in PyTorch to ordinary nn.Module?

Tags: python, pytorch, torchscript

I am loading the **torchscript** model in the following way:

```
model = torch.jit.load("model.pt").to(device)
```

The children modules of this model are identified as `RecursiveScriptModule`. I would like to finetune the uploaded weights and in order to make it simplier and cast them to `torch.float32` It is preferable to convert all this stuff to ordinary **PyTorch** `nn.Module`.

In the official docs https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html it is told how to convert `nn.Module` to `torchscript`, but I have not found any examples in doing this in the opposite direction. Is there a way to do this?

P.S the example of loading model pretrained model is given here:  https://github.com/openai/CLIP/blob/main/notebooks/Interacting_with_CLIP.ipynb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to load it as it e.g. `state_dict = torch.load(src).state_dict()`.
Then manually convert every key and value `new_v = state_dict[k].cpu().float()`.